# call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object mysqli

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am getting this error when I submit the form. 
call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object
I have checked the console as well. It shows all the values I enter in the form. The values are getting stored in json variable and passed to the php page.It is on the bind_param() function, it shows the error. The same code works for the remaining 2 pages of my project, but it is not working for this one. Please help

Here is the PHP code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "kites";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    alert("Connection failed");
}
else
{
// Check for empty fields
  if(
        empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['firstname']) || empty($_POST['lastname']) || empty($_POST['age']) || empty($_POST['contact']) || empty($_POST['streetname']) || empty($_POST['buildingname']) || empty($_POST['landmark']) || empty($_POST['area']) || empty($_POST['pincode']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['univ']) || empty($_POST['qualification']) || empty($_POST['dialcode']) || empty($_POST['countrycode']) || empty($_POST['bloodgroup']) || empty($_POST['school'])  
     )
  {  
  echo json_encode(array('status'=>false,'msg'=>'No arguments provided'));
  }
  else if(is_numeric($_POST['firstname']) && is_numeric($_POST['lastname']))
  {
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>false,'msg'=>'Name should not contain numbers. Please try again'));
  }
  else if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>false,'msg'=>'Check your email id and try again'));
  }
  else if(!is_numeric($_POST['age']))
  {
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>false,'msg'=>'Age should contain only numbers'));
  }

  else{
         $username = $_POST['username'];
         $password = $_POST['password'];
         $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
         $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
         $age = $_POST['age'];
         $bloodgroup = $_POST['bloodgroup'];
         $contact = $_POST['contact'];
         $streetname = $_POST['streetname'];
         $buildingname = $_POST['buildingname'];
         $landmark = $_POST['landmark'];
         $area = $_POST['area'];
         $pincode = $_POST['pincode'];
         $email = $_POST['email'];
         $univ = $_POST['univ'];
         $school = $_POST['school'];
         $qualification = $_POST['qualification'];
         $dialcode = $_POST['dialcode'];
         $countrycode = $_POST['countrycode'];
        // $sql = "INSERT INTO join_form (name,email,contact,role,dialcode,countrycode) VALUES ('$name','$email','$contact','$role','$dialcode','$countrycode')";
         $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO register_form(username,password,firstname,lastname,age,bloodgroup,contact,streetname,buildingname,landmark,area,pincode,email,univ,school,qualification,dialcode,countrycode) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssssisssssssssssss",$username,$password,$firstname,$lastname,$age,$bloodgroup,$contact,$streetname,$buildingname,$landmark,$area,$pincode,$email,$univ,$school,$qualification,$dialcode,$countrycode);
        $sql = $stmt->execute();
        if ($sql) {
          echo json_encode(array('status'=>true,'msg'=>"New record created successfully"));
       //   // Create the email and send the message
       // $to = 'naitikgada1995@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
       // $email_subject = "Registration Successfull:  $name";
       // $email_body = "We have sent this mail to inform you that your registration is successfull\n\n"
       //                ."Here are the details:\n\n"
       //                ."Name: $name\n\nEmail: $email\n\nContact:$contact\n\nPassword: $password\n\n";
       // $headers = "From: noreply@kiddo.com\n";
       // $headers .= "Reply-To: $email";  
       // mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
       // // $response['status'] = 'true';
        } 
        else {    
          echo json_encode(array('status'=>false,'msg'=>'Enter different email id or contact number and try again'));
        // return false;
        // $response['feedback'] = 'false';
        // $response['message'] = 'Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again. Try entering a different email id and contact number';
        // echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
      }
    // header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);


  }
}     
?>
```

Comment: Check the error, `if(!$stmt){ echo $conn->error;` put that before execute()

Comment: Set full error message this here from php_error

Comment: check for errors, you're not doing that. Plus, no idea if your form is correct, the one you didn't include in your question. Take it up with the person who gave you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if there is any spelling mistake or any other error in this line in the query

```
         $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO register_form(username,password,firstname,lastname,age,bloodgroup,contact,streetname,buildingname,landmark,area,pincode,email,univ,school,qualification,dialcode,countrycode) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Comment: spelling mistake in the database column. ty :)